# JSON inside XML

Tags: xml, json, xml-parsing

I want to know about standard and best practice in :

**Case Scenario :**

If a **xml standard** exist by **"XYZ SPECIFICATION" *(ex : BPMN Specification)*** like :

```
<home>
<person name="ZEN" />
<person name="PAUL" />
<animal name="DOG" />
<animal name="CAT" />
</home>
```

and  "XYZ SPECIFICATION" also provide **extension element** to define your own tag like :

```
   <home>
    <person name="ZEN" />
    <person name="PAUL" />
    <animal name="DOG" />
    <animal name="CAT" />
    <extension>
    <instrument-list>
    <type name="acoustic">
      <instrument name="GUITAR" />
      <instrument name="VIOLIN"  />
    </type>
    <type name="electronic">
      <instrument name="GUITAR" />
      <instrument name="VIOLIN"/>
    </type>
    </instrument-list>
    </extension>
    </home>
```

Tag defined by standard are used by other client parser , they don't need to parse extension tag so i was thinking that it would be better to compress extension element using json (because json takes less space in compare to xml) :

```
  <home>
    <person name="ZEN" />
    <person name="PAUL" />
    <animal name="DOG" />
    <animal name="CAT" />
    <extension>
    <instrument-list>{"type":[{"name":"acoustic","instrument":[{"name":"GUITAR"},{"name":"VIOLIN"}]},{"name":"electronic","instrument":[{"name":"GUITAR"},{"name":"VIOLIN"}]}]}</instrument-list>
    </extension>
    </home>
```

or

```
<home>
    <person name="ZEN" />
    <person name="PAUL" />
    <animal name="DOG" />
    <animal name="CAT" />
    <extension>
    <instrument-list><![CDATA[ {"type":[{"name":"acoustic","instrument":[{"name":"GUITAR"},{"name":"VIOLIN"}]},{"name":"electronic","instrument":[{"name":"GUITAR"},{"name":"VIOLIN"}]}]} ]]></instrument-list>
    </extension>
    </home>
```

Is it violates standard and best practices ?

Comment: Pick XML or JSON that way you don't have to process the data through two different parsers. At the end of the day you will probably be getting the worst of both worlds

Answer (score 4):

There is no "XYZ specification" per say. Though I would recommend reading up on XML and its specification because you will need to take into consideration of escaping the following characters inside your JSON for things to work nicely with XML parsers.

```
XML escape characters.
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;

or use

<![CDATA[ ]]>
```